# How to handle ALL error messages, even when a command does not work?

Tags: linux, bash

I am a bit rusty on my bash shell scripting.  I have created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

display_usage() {
        echo -e "\nUsage: This script must be run with both a valid source and a target client name."
        echo -e "Example: ./createClientRolesRespChart <source client name> <target client name>\n"
        }

mv $1 $2

# If less than two arguments supplied, display usage
if [  $# -le 1 ]; then
        display_usage
        exit 1
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Created new response chart for the $2 client."
   exit 0
else
    echo "[Error] Move (mv) command failed. Please check parameters are correct."
    exit 1
fi
```

The script works, BUT if I enter a wrong filename, the command fails, buy it still prints the success message.  Any hints.  Should be an easy thing.  I just forget :(

```
bash-3.2$ ./createClientRolesRespChart foo bar
mv: rename foo to bar: No such file or directory
Created new response chart for the bar client.
```

Comment: Aside: `echo -e` is best replaced with `printf`; see the POSIX spec for `echo`, especially the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: Anyhow -- `if mv "$1" "$2"; then ...success...; else ...failure...; fi` is much better practice than relying on `$?`, which is volatile (every command you run changes its value) and easy to accidentally disrupt. And be careful of the quoting; using `mv $1 $2` instead of `mv "$1" "$2"` and you're going to have a bad time with filenames with spaces.

Comment: I recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), especially when you're starting out. It'll point out a bunch of common mistakes and bad habits before they cause trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` only says whether the last command succeeded. In your case, you're doing an `mv`, which is failing, then looking at the argument count, then looking at `$?`, which will now contain the result of the argument count check, and not of the `mv`. To fix it, switch the argument count check and the `mv`.